# What should be server bandwidth speed of for WSS 3.0?

Tags: wss-3.0, networking, infrastructure

Can someone please suggest on recommended internet speed of a VPS for Sharepoint (WSS3.0) usage with 1000 users database and 100 users online at any given point of time?

Is 24 MBPS uplink enough?

Thx
saumil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, aim for 100Mbit if you can.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the type of content in the system and what the users will be doing with it.  If documents are frequently being added or updated bandwidth can be heavier than if people are looking at some basic static content.

It is possible to run perfmon to view various common bottlenecks to validate, but I would be worried about having so little bandwidth.